# Exclamation and question marks in JavaScript comments?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I was going through some code and found these two:

```
//   ! if (!playbackState) return
```

```
//   ?  if (isSpotify) setPlayerTime(playbackState.position)
```

In VS Code, the line with "!" was highlighted in red, the other one was highlighted in blue. Couldn't find any info on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am taking a jump (or a bit of a leap since some context is missing) and assuming you have [better-comments](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aaron-bond.better-comments) installed

To which end, the below is found in my `settings.json` which does explain this

```json
"better-comments.tags": [
  {
     "tag": "!",
     "color": "#FF2D00",
     "strikethrough": false,
     "underline": false,
     "backgroundColor": "transparent",
     "bold": false,
     "italic": false
  },
  {
     "tag": "?",
     "color": "#3498DB",
     "strikethrough": false,
     "underline": false,
     "backgroundColor": "transparent",
     "bold": false,
     "italic": false
   }
}
```

Comment: Curious. I couldn't find any usage of this in the project, but I'm guessing that it's hidden somewhere anyway. Thanks you.

Comment: AFAIK this is defaults for better-comments, and you can change this in your settings.json